# Firefox displays all webpages wrong

Tags: css, firefox

I have a strange problem with FF. It displays every webpage in the wrong way. No background colors are used - they are always white. Links are always blue, and tables have always a black border around it. FF also does not display an background images. I have no idea how this could happen. For me it seems, that FF uses for all webpages the same css (at least partially) and ignores the css shiped with the page.

Any hints? I could imagine that this problem could be trivially fixed but I do not know how.

Comment: are you using adblock plus addon for firefox ?

Comment: could you share your about:support information here or via pastebin so that we can have some idea of what addons and settings are involved?

Comment: Yepp, I am using adblock plus. I disabled without success.

Comment: Here is about:support: http://pastebin.com/ENhkujff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look for settings -> content -> colors. Then check the lowermost checkbox "allow pages to use different colrs than those above". Please take into account that I am using the german version of Firefox. Thus, the labelling can differ from my description.

Comment: Great, it works. I do not how how this box has been disabled. I have not done this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Start by emptying the cache and restarting. If that doesn't work, uninstall FF, remove its files from %AppData%, and start fresh. The profile may be corrupted (and you can back up your profile next time so that it can be restored if something like this happens).